# Changing file's properties so you could only add text to it, is it possible?

Tags: command-line, password, text-editor, text-processing

Is it possible to make deleting text from a text file impossible while still being able to add text to it?

For example, let's say i have a text file with these three letters in it :

A
B
C

How can i prevent anybody (including superuser) from deleting these letters while still being able to add new letters to the file?

If there is no possibility of doing so , how can i set a password so I could edit this text file only when I type it in? (password different than superuser's password)

Could you recommend me any command/programme?

Thank you in advance, I am an ubuntu newbie.

Comment: Not possible.  The superuser can do literally whatever he/she wants, that's why you're not supposed to log in as `root` unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Being able to write to a file also means being able to delete its content.

Comment: @Daniel - Not true, one can restrict root with both apparmor and selinux.

Answer (score 1):

You can to some extent with chattr.

Run the command

```
sudo chattr +a file
```

See man chattr for details.

Note: root (or anyone with sudo/root access) can change the file back.

You can restrict root to ro access with apparmor, and in that event you would have to have another user to append the file.

Comment: And why can't root just change apparmor settings to enable access?

Comment: @muru - You have to configure apparmor to restrict root. I have an old blog post about this http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/shared-terminal-sessions-over-ssh/ and a few old profiles you can play with http://bodhizazen.net/aa-profiles/bodhizazen/ubuntu-10.04/usr.local.bin.jailbash You can also play with engard linux http://www.engardelinux.org/ . Go ahead, install it, and log into a terminal as root. The root account is confined by selinux.

Comment: @muru - Of course you also need to use encryption, limit physical access / booting a live USB, use HIDS, etc ;) I am going to bet chattr is sufficient in this case.

Answer (score 0):

KISS! (keep it simple ...)

How about archiving this file with password (ZIP, 7Z, arj etc...), and allow users to work only with changeable part?

See:

[header.txt]

```
A B C
by Gero
```

[contents.txt]

```
whatever users want to change or have rights to change
```

On printing or on producing final document:

```
cat header.txt contents.txt
```

To protect your precious "ABC", you should compress `header.txt` into password-locked archive. That's only case when the root user could not change your text without knowing archive's password.

Such approach is system and architecture independent: do not <s>put all eggs into same basket</s> store constant and variating data in the file which does not allow different access level to its different parts.